# Login Dialog Loop Alert For Facebook App

Tags: facebook

I received an alert for my Facebook app which says "Your app repeatedly redirects people to the Login Dialog after they decline permissions requests. Please update your app so it meets our Platform Policies for providing a great user experience."

Can anyone help me in fixing it. Here is the code

```
    <?php
if (!empty($_GET['i'])) {
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['imguris'] = $_GET['i']; 
}

require( '../../../../wp-load.php' );

$toptions = get_option('sample_theme_options');

if (!empty($toptions['fbappid']) && !empty($toptions['fbapisecret'])) {

    $fbconfig['appid' ]     = $toptions['fbappid'];
    $fbconfig['secret']     = $toptions['fbapisecret'];
    $fbconfig['baseurl']    = get_bloginfo('template_url')."/fb/index.php";
    //print_r($fbconfig);

    if (isset($_GET['request_ids'])){

    }

    $user            =   null; //facebook user uid
    try{
        include_once "facebook.php";
    }
    catch(Exception $o){
        error_log($o);
    }

    $facebook = new t_Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
      'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
      'cookie' => true,
    ));

    $user       = $facebook->getUser();    
    $loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                'scope'         => 'publish_stream',
                'redirect_uri'  => $fbconfig['baseurl'])
    );

    function d($d){
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($d);
        echo '</pre>';
    }

    if (!$user) { ?>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
        window.top.location.href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>"; 
        </script>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if ($user){
        if (isset($_SESSION['imguris'])) {
            $imguri = str_replace(get_option('home'), "", $_SESSION['imguris']);
            $imguri = '../../../../'.$imguri;               
            $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
            $args = array('message' => $toptions['covtitle']);
            $args['image'] = '@' . realpath($imguri);
            try {
                    $data = $facebook->api('/'.$user.'/photos', 'post', $args);
                    //print_r($data);
            } catch (t_FacebookApiException $e) {
                    //d($e);
            }
            if (isset($data['id'])) {
                if (isset($toptions['instructionsurl'])) {
                    $redir = $toptions['instructionsurl'];
                } else {
                    $redir = get_option('home');
                }
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'> window.top.location.href='".$redir."'; </script>";
            }
        }
    } 

} else {
    if (isset($toptions['instructionsurl'])) {
        $redir = $toptions['instructionsurl'];
    } else {
        $redir = get_option('home');
    }
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> window.top.location.href='".$redir."'; </script>";
}
```

?>

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't about the code, it's about the workflow. FB user experience policies state that an app should not repeatedly ask users for permissions if they keep refusing them. However it should also provide users with a clear way to grant those permissions if they decide so. There is no specific solution to achieve this behavior, but FB recommends developers separate their essential and non-essential permission requests, i.e. only ask for basic read permissions on login and then before the app attempts to post content on FB verify that you have the necessary write permissions, and present the user with the appropriate permission request if not.

Check out [FB permissions documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions) for more info on possible Developer Alerts and proposed courses of action to resolve them.